# Where are Cygwin Packages Installed?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, cmake

I've recently installed cygwin64 on my Windows 10 machine in an attempt to build a project using cmake (Through CLion).

The project has lz4 as a dependency and when running the cygwin setup, there's a gui where you can select packages to install.

One of the default packages is `liblz4_1` so I made sure it remained selected and installed the packages.

However when trying to build my project, I get a fatal cmake error 'fatal error: lz4.h: No such file or directory'.

So I gather cmake doesn't know where to look for the header files, and it turns out neither do I.

I've searched through `C:\cygwin64\usr\include` and in fact used Windows search through the entire `C:\cygwin64` folder and could not find any file with `lz4` in its name.

So, does anyone know where the packages installed during setup actually get stored?

Comment: They should be contained within the Cygwin64 directory.

Comment: @Ramhound in `usr\include` ? because its not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the `liblz4-devel` package.
You can use `cygcheck` to identify the package containing a specific file

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/include/lz4.h
Found 1 matches for usr/include/lz4.h
liblz4-devel-1.7.5-1 - liblz4-devel: LZ4 de/compressor
```

Answer (score 0):

They were in 'usr\include', I just had to install the package labeled plain 'lz4'.